# NSDate not showing exact days passed

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

I made a small program to calculate the difference between two dates, and output the number of days, and months passed. The program shows the number of months, and number of days fine, separately. However, when I join them together in a flag, the output only shows the right number of months, and "12" for the number of days, no matter what date I put in. I've also tried the inline `components: (NSDayCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit`), but the same problem occurs. Here is my code. Thanks much for any help!

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
 @autoreleasepool {
        NSDate *startDate=[NSDate dateWithString:@"2004-2-24 1:54:10 +0600"];
        NSDate *today=[NSDate date];
        NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
        NSUInteger flags = NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit;
        NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components: flags  fromDate:startDate toDate:today options:0];
        NSInteger days = [components day];
        NSInteger months = [components month];
        NSLog(@"%li",(long)days);
        NSLog(@"%li",(long)months);  
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
 2013-05-05 14:49:36.943 calenderCalc[4111:303] 12
 2013-05-05 14:49:36.944 calenderCalc[4111:303] 110
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The output only shows "12" for the number of days, no matter what date I put in.

Are you sure? When I use a `startDate` of `@"2013-4-30 1:54:10 +0600"`, I see `days` is 6 and `months` is 0. Your code looks fine.

*Edit*

Here's how to compare 2 dates' "day of month", regardless of whether or not they're in the same month or year.

```
NSCalendar* gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] ;
NSDate* startDate = [NSDate dateWithString:@"2013-4-18 1:54:10 +0600"] ;
NSDate* today     = [NSDate dateWithString:@"2013-5-05 1:54:10 +0600"] ;
NSDateComponents* startDateComponents = [gregorian components:NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:startDate] ;
NSDateComponents* todayComponents     = [gregorian components:NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:today] ;
int daysApart = fabs(startDateComponents.day - todayComponents.day) ;
```

Comment: Hm, I just tried that date on mine, and I did indeed get 6 and 0. However, I tried other dates such as 1997-2-24, 2001-1-13, and just random dates like that, and I'm getting the wrong numbers such as 12, 21, etc.

Comment: Oh I think I found my mistake, it is giving me just the number "days" from that date. What if I wanted to include the days in the month as well? Would I have to manually do this, or is there an easier way? What I mean is: From 1/1/12 to 1/1/13, there are 365 days, but the difference is 0 (which is what I'm getting).

Comment: It all depends on which `CalendarUnit` flags you specify. If you specify `(NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit)`, then the resulting NSDateComponents will indicate how many months + how many days are between the 2 dates. Your original example shows that, if you add 110 months then add 12 days to February 24, 2004, you get today's date. This is the sort of answer you're looking for, right?

Comment: Sort of, but I'm not getting that value though. It is giving me the difference of dates, numerically, which is great, but I want it calculate the days including all the years that are passed. For example: between the dates 1/1/13, and 2/4/13, there is difference of 3 "days," but there was actually 35 or so days in between.

Comment: Gotcha. Instead of using `components:fromDate:toDate:options:`, use `components:fromDate:` for both `startDate` and `today`. Then, calculate the difference between both NSDateComponents' `day`s.

Comment: Thanks! But, how exactly would I do this? If I do that separately, then wouldn't there be a date missing?